Table column header title not showing on Sequoia
When a Table is placed inside a List, the Table column title is not showing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Code:
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let emailAddress: String
    let id = UUID()


    var fullName: String { givenName + " " + familyName }
}
struct TableView: View {
    @State private var people = [
        Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez", emailAddress: "juanchavez@icloud.com"),
        Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen", emailAddress: "meichen@icloud.com"),
        Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark", emailAddress: "tomclark@icloud.com"),
        Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar", emailAddress: "gitakumar@icloud.com")
    ]
    var body: some View {
        Table(people) {
            TableColumn("Give Name", value: \.givenName)
            TableColumn("Family Name", value: \.familyName)
            TableColumn("Email Address", value: \.emailAddress)
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 100)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            TableView()
        }
    }
}


If List is replaced with anything else (ScrollView) it works fine.

List uses its own styling and seem to clash with the Table/TableView,
especially on MacOS.
IMHO, you are using the wrong tool (List) to display a Table,
use the Table on its own.
